# Angular get data from the server MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data from the server.Get Users function has the data and I am trying to pass it to the AdminController.js. What am  I doing wrong?
I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

```
namespace VTS.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetUsers()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonString = string.Empty;
            TributaryEntities db = new TributaryEntities();
            var listUsers = (from user in db.PSP_BatchOrderDriver select new   { ID = user.ID, Fname = user.FirstName, LastName = user.LastName }).ToList();
            string output = jss.Serialize(listUsers);
            var test = Json(jss.Serialize(output));
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

AdminController.js file

```
'user strict';
myApp.controller('AdminController',

function AdminControllerl($timeout, $q, $log) 
{
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled = false;

    self.employees = loadAll();

    function loadAll($http)
    {
       var allEmployees = $http.post('Controllers/AdminController/GetUsers');
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `var allEmployees = $http.post('Controllers/Admin/GetUsers');`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including '$http' in controller's arguments

```
'user strict';
myApp.controller('AdminController',

function AdminControllerl($timeout, $q, $log, $http) 
{
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled = false;

    self.employees = loadAll();

    function loadAll()
    {
       var allEmployees = $http.post('Controllers/AdminController/GetUsers');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but I get the same error: 'Cannot read property 'post' of undefined'

Comment: also, remove the '$http' from loadAll function definition

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but now I can not find the path to 'Controllers/AdminController/GetUsers'

Comment: I am not sure about the asp controllers, but can you try changing the url to 'Admin/GetUsers' instead of 'Controllers/AdminController/GetUsers'

Comment: Thank you I got it working like ''../Admin/GetUsers/''